# CUDA shared memory read/write order within a single thread

Tags: cuda

The shared memory is not synchronized between threads in a block. But I don't know if the shared memory is synchronized with the writer thread.

For example, in this example:

```
__global__ void kernel()
{
    __shared__ int i, j;

    if(threadIdx.x == 0)
    {
        i = 10;
        j = i;
    }

   // #1
}
```

Is it guaranteed at `#1` that, for thread 0, `i=10` and `j=10`, or do I need some memory fence or introduce a local variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that by

> for thread 0

you mean, "the thread that passed the if-test".  And for the sake of this discussion, I will assume there is only one of those.

Yes, it's guaranteed.  Otherwise [basic C++ compliance](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#c-language-support) would be broken in CUDA.

Challenges in CUDA may arise in inter-thread communication or behavior.  However you don't have that in view in your question.

As an example, it is certainly not guaranteed that for some other thread, `i` will be visible as 10, without some sort of [fence or barrier](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#memory-fence-functions).